# Почему выдаёт ошибку "Невозможно открыть файл"?

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    void main()
    {
int i;
double x,y;
FILE *fin, *fout;

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");

fin=fopen("razvetv1.in","r");
if(fin == NULL)
{
    printf("Невозможно открыть файл razvetv1.in\n");
    system("PAUSE");return;
}
fout=fopen("razvetv1.out","w");
if(fout == NULL)
{
    printf("Невозможно открыть файл razvetv1.out\n");
    system("PAUSE");return;
}
while(fscanf(fin,"%lf",&x) !=EOF)
{
    if (x < 3)
    {
        y=log(0.9*pow(x,2)+0.5); i=1;
    }
    else if (x <= 5)
    {
        y=((2.9*sqrt(fabs(sin(x)))/(9-cos(2*x))))-(4*sqrt(x)); i=2;
    }
    else
    {
        y=0.8*pow(x,3)-2.4*pow(x,2)-3*x-5; i=3;
    }
    printf("Вычисление функции по %1d-й зависимости:\n",i);
    printf("x=%3.1lf y=%13.6le\n\n",x,y);
    fprintf(fout,"Вычисление функции по %1d-1 зависимости:\n",i);
    fprintf(fout,"x=%3.1lf y=%13.6le\n\n",x,y);
}
fcloseall();
system("PAUSE");
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что функция fopen возвращает NULL.

Comment: Значит, нет у вас такого файла... Или нет прав его открывать.

Comment: Так, и что мне с этим сделать можно?

Comment: найти файл.....

Comment: Добавьте после вызова `printf` вызов `perror("");` для получения сообщения об ошибке от системы.

Comment: Попробуйте указать **полный** путь к фaйлу - типа `fopen("c:\\Data\\Files\\razvetv1.in","r");` - может, у вас он *не* в текущем каталоге.